# How to set webview mobile to desktop mode using Xamarin

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, android-webview

Tried this

```
public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
{
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        webView.Source = "https://www.example.com/";
        webView.Navigating += WebView_Navigating;
    }

    private void WebView_Navigating(object sender, WebNavigatingEventArgs e)
    {
        // Set the User-Agent string to a desktop browser user agent
        webView.Eval("navigator.userAgent = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/58.0.3029.110 Safari/537.36'");
    }
}
```

please help in changing to desktop mode using Xamarin

Comment: For more information, you can refer to this doc: [Create the custom renderer on android](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/custom-renderer/hybridwebview#create-the-custom-renderer-on-android) by official.

Answer (score 0):

In Android you have to implement a custom renderer.

Create a Custom Renderer(DesktopWebViewRenderer.cs) in Android folder:

```
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(WebView), typeof(DesktopWebViewRenderer))]
namespace forms.Droid
{
    public class DesktopWebViewRenderer : WebViewRenderer
    {
        public DesktopWebViewRenderer(Context context): base(context)
        {
        }

        protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<WebView> e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged(e);

            Control.Settings.UserAgentString
                = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/58.0.3029.110 Safari/537.36";

        }
    }
}
```